# Run a second antenna on my car with Veins

Tags: omnet++

In my default Veins scenario (the one in the example) I need a second antenna on my car. In `Car.ned` I entered the following code (doing copy and paste from connections block):

```
nic2.upperLayerOut --> appl2.lowerLayerIn;
nic2.upperLayerIn <-- appl2.lowerLayerOut;
nic2.upperControlOut --> appl2.lowerControlIn;
nic2.upperControlIn <-- appl2.lowerControlOut;
veinsradioIn2 --> nic2.radioIn;
```

Now I have two antennas on my node (and they work!). But how can I decide who sends and who receives? In this way I just changed the topology of the network, but I can't handle the communications! I need to reach this scenario: node->node (first antenna) and node->RSU (second antenna). I think I should work on `TraCIDemo11p.cc` and `TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc`, but the code is immense and I get lost too easily. The final target is to make sure that these two antennas work with different protocols, but at the moment I make do with the same protocol and with these two different channels I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to give a concise answer to your question, because it has multiple components, but here are some important things you should look at:

First off: right now, what you've done is specified a car with two network interfaces (`nic` and `nic2`) and two separate applications (`appl` and `appl2`). I think, by your description, that is not what you want. I would suggest that your first step is to create an application interface that has connections to two network interfaces. This means creating the corresponding `.ned` file. You can use `./veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.ned` as an example. Make sure to define your application object `appl` (in `Car.ned`) as that `.ned` file and connect both of these in the way you described. You'll then have 8 channels from your application to the two network interfaces (I'd call them `appl.nic1LayerIn`, `appl.nic1ControlIn`, `appl.nic2LayerIn` and so on).

After that, you will want to write logic that decides whether a particular message should go to the one network interface, or to the other, and put that code in your application's source. To communicate with the different network interfaces you'll just use the respective channels. To see how this works you'll need to dig in the veins source code a little bit: the code interacting with the channels is not directly in the `TraCIDemo11p` source, but somewhere in a super class there-of (I think it is `BaseWaveApplLayer`, but I'm not 100% sure). You could either modify those files to work with multiple antennae, or create new source files -- I'm not sure which one is less code, though.

Another thing to remember is that you'll need to provide the corresponding settings in the `omnetpp.ini` too (`*.**.nic2...`, analogous to `*.**.nic...`). I'm not sure what veins will do with two antennae at the same position (it might lead to some weird effects), but I also don't remember where the antenna position is specified.